# Can i still get the stone of Barenziah in astrid's room?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Can you still get the one in Astrid's room after you have completed the final dark brotherhood quest? because I have already completed it and i didn't notice a stone.

Answer (score 1):

You can still get the Stone of Barenziah from Astrid's room even after the DB sanctuary has burned down.

Here is a screenshot of the same.

[image: Stone of Barenziah Astrid's Room after DB sack]

If you are having trouble locating the stones, there is a mod that gives quest marker type arrows to the stones available on PC, XBox One and PS4.

Comment: That doesn't look like a screenshot of the burned-down sanctuary.